# How to reorder the column in pandas based on values of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column in a dataframe by shifting the index of existing column based on the value of that column.

expected dataframe:
[image: ataframe]

I thought .diff() function can help me here and for the parameter 'periods', I can mention the column name I want new column to shift by.

```py
df['expected_new_col']= df['Age'].diff(periods = df['d_id_max'])
```

As you can see from the image, the col 'Expected_new_col' is based on the col 'Age' and col 'd_id_max'. So for Age 14, if we shift 2 indexes, we get 55, for Age 25. if we shift 1 index, we get 55 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understood your problem, you can do it like this (if your dataframe index is 0, 1, 2, 3 ...) :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Sam', 'Andrea', 'Alex', 'Robin', 'Kia', 'Sia'], 'Age':[14,25,55,8,21,43], 'd_id_max':[2,1,1,2,2,2]})

df['Expected_new_col'] = df.loc[df.index + df.d_id_max, 'Age'].to_numpy()

print(df)
```

This code can raise an error if you don't handle the case where df.index + df.d_id_max is greater than the number of rows in your dataframe.

Comment: This code gives me following error: 'can only perform ops with scalar values'.

Comment: What are your Python and Pandas versions ? Otherwise, you can try to replace the third line with this one : df['Expected_new_col'] = df.loc[df.index.to_numpy() + df.d_id_max.to_numpy(), 'Age'].to_numpy()

Comment: My python Version is 3.6

Comment: And your version of Pandas ? You can use these lines in the Python interpreter to find it :

import pandas as pd
pd.__version__

If your version is older than the  0.24.0, the "to_numpy()" doesn't exist. You can use the "values" attribute instead.

Comment: my pandas version is 0.24.2

Comment: My python Version is 3.7.3

Comment: Did you try to handle th case where df.index + df.d_id_max is out of bound ?
For example, you can replace the second line with this one :
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Sam', 'Andrea', 'Alex', 'Robin', 'Kia', 'Sia'], 'Age':[14,25,55,8,21,43], 'd_id_max':[2,1,1,2,0,0]})

Comment: yes, its giving me the right output now, only thing is d_id_max column is generated from the previous operation and I have change last two rows by 0.

Comment: Although I am able to create the desired output if I am creating a new dataframe , but I am not able to do the same, when I am passing this code ****df['Expected_new_col'] = df.loc[df.index + df.d_id_max, 'Age'].to_numpy()*** to a already existing dataframe. I want to replicate the same solution to a large dataset and the column d_id_max has values from 1 to 1000. When I am implementing the code I am still getting the same error  ''can only perform ops with scalar values''.

Comment: Hi, I think the problem comes again from the case where df.index + df._d_id_max is out of bound. You can handle this case in a generic way with this line : ***df['Expected_new_col'] = df.loc[np.minimum(df.index + df.d_id_max, df.index.max()), 'Age'].to_numpy()***
The np.minimum function will return the greatest index value if df.index + df.d_id_max is out of bound.